# Помогите с Makefile

Tags: c, include, makefile

Я не так давно программирую и я знаком с простейшими Makefile ами и утилитой make , но тут я ничего не разберу и времени совсем нет кто объяснит вот эти строчки , большое спасибо !:

```
bin/test_button: src/test_button.c lib/ev3c.a //я понимаю что эти 2 файла
                                                       //зависимости 
    mkdir -p $(@D)// вот что означает -P $(@D) ??
    $(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude // вот эту строку вообще я не понял.
```

Вот то что объявлялось в начале этого файла :

```
CFLAGS += -O3
ifndef RANLIB
    RANLIB = ranlib
endif
```

Вот сам файл с которым не надо разобраться :

```
CFLAGS += -O3
ifndef RANLIB
    RANLIB = ranlib
endif

all: lib/ev3c.a bin/test_sensor bin/test_motor bin/test_lcd bin/test_button bin/test_led bin/test_battery

obj/%.o: src/%.c include/%.h include/ev3c.h Makefile
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude

lib/ev3c.a: obj/ev3c_core.o obj/ev3c_lcd.o obj/ev3c_sensor.o obj/ev3c_motor.o obj/ev3c_button.o obj/ev3c_led.o obj/ev3c_battery.o
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(AR) rc $@ $^ && $(RANLIB) $@

bin/test_sensor: src/test_sensor.c lib/ev3c.a
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude

bin/test_motor: src/test_motor.c lib/ev3c.a
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude

bin/test_lcd: src/test_lcd.c lib/ev3c.a
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude

bin/test_button: src/test_button.c lib/ev3c.a
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude

bin/test_led: src/test_led.c lib/ev3c.a
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude

bin/test_battery: src/test_battery.c lib/ev3c.a
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) -o $@ $< lib/ev3c.a $(CFLAGS) -Iinclude

documentation: include/*.h
    mkdir -p /tmp/ev3DocumentationTemp
    naturaldocs -i . -xi ./ev3c_documentation -o HTML ev3c_documentation -p /tmp/ev3DocumentationTemp

.PHONY: all clean

clean:
    rm -rf obj lib bin
    rm -f *~
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Name-Index.html#Name-Index

Comment: Очевидно даже из кода, не читая мануал, *создаёт каталог выходного файла*. Вторая строка -- явный вызов компилятора с параметрами. Там скорее всего дублицирование библиотеки, да и вообще в простых случаях типа этого можно использовать неявные цели `make`.